# How to find every <a href="" > for html using regular expression(JS)

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's my doubt. I get the line(regular expression) which gets every href of my html, but I need to get the ones which are out of my domain. I think there are something specific that can help me to do that, or some particular tip.

Here is my regular expression:

```
var re=/(?:<a *(?:(?!href)(?:\w)+="(?:[^"]+)")* *)href="([^"]+)"/g;
```

I'm using node.js. So what im doing is run it(someFile.js). The little .js just receive myHtmlpage.html and try to get every href out of that domain.

//edit
The idea is try to change that regex, I know it can be a little bit silly, but I need to use regex

Comment: Is your HTML a string? Why don't you just use `document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')` and filter out the results with a `for` loop or `forEach`?

Comment: Im using node.js. So what im doing is run it(someFile.js). 
The little .js just receive myHtmlpage.html and try to get every href

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with an attribute selector using `querySelectorAll` and a parameter NOT matching your domain.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a[href]:not([href='yourdomain'])");
```

You shouldn't regex html.

Comment: The `!=` attribute selector isn't listed on the [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) page, I think that's a [jQuery Sizzle](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) addition

Comment: This does not include any answer to the actual question. Also it still includes links from the domain - merely no exact fits (^=).

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest avoiding Regular Expressions to parse HTML (an irregular language), and instead using JavaScript:

```
/* uses Array.prototype.filter on the NodeList returned
   by document.querySelectorAll, retains only those elements
   that match the supplied filter expression:
*/
var els = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(a){
    /* assesses whether the href of the a elements link to a different
       domain than the current domain; if so that element is retained
       and forms part of the resulting array:
    */
    return a.href.indexOf(document.location.host) == -1;
// using Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over the created array:
}).forEach(function(a){
    /* adds the classname 'outofdomain' to the classList,
       obviously amend this to do whatever you prefer:
    */
    a.classList.add('outofdomain');
});

console.log(els);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/B2vV2/).

And for those browsers that dislike the above approach (IE8 and lower):

```
    // get all the 'a' elements:
var aElems = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    // get the current domain's hostname:
    host = document.location.hostname,
    // create an array to push the matched elements:
    outofdomain = [];

// iterating over the 'a' elements found earlier:
for (var i = 0, len = aElems.length; i < len; i++){
    // if the hostname is not found in the href
    if (aElems[i].href.indexOf(host) == -1){
        // we add it into the array:
        outofdomain.push(aElems[i]);
        // set the class-name:
        aElems[i].className = 'outofdomain';
    }
}

console.log(outofdomain);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/B2vV2/2/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Comment: Using `[].filter.call(host object)` will fail in IE 8 and lower. The *document.links* property (available in every browser ever) is a list of all links in a page.

Comment: That's true; but (for some reason) I intrinsically dislike `document.links` and used `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` instead for the, basically, oldIE version since added to meet your valid concern.

Comment: I see why people avoid to use regex, thank you. But thats my problem, I need to use it.

Comment: *links* has benefits in that it doesn't get anchors, is live (as is the returned object from *getElementsByTagName*), and since it's a property, is very fast. It's also fairly easy to have a *toArray* function that converts a collection to an array so native methods can be used (avoding the host object/native method issue with older IE). But since the OP wants to do this at the server on an HTML string, I guess DOM methods are out.